# how to change query builder to eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

```
$regu = DB::table('patrol_transactions as a')
    ->leftJoin('patrol_users as b', 'a.patrol_user_id', 'b.id')
    ->where('client_location_id', auth::user()->client_location_id)
    ->whereBetween('a.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
    ->select('patrol_user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'b.name as name')
    ->groupBy('patrol_user_id', 'name')
    ->get();
```

##### PatrolTansaction.php

```
public function patrolUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PatrolUser::class, 'patrol_user_id');
}
```

I have a query builder code like the one above, what would it look like if it was changed to eloquent?

Comment: What have you tried? Come up with some tries and if you still do not understand, we will then be able to help based on that

Comment: are you using modals? If you want a proper solution than using plain SQL I can provide it if you can edit your initial post with the database structure (simplified) and how they are related

Comment: I have edited my post by adding a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per your code, **you already defined the relationship** `patrolUser()`, so there is no need to use `JOIN` to merge it again. U**se `with()` to load the relationship**.

```
$regu = PatrolTransaction::where('client_location_id', auth::user()->client_location_id)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
    ->with(['patrolUser:id,name'])
    ->select('patrol_user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('patrol_user_id', 'name')
    ->get();
```